# UnicodeDecodeError on join

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I have a list with some strings (most of which I fetched from a sqlite3 database):

```
stats_list = ['Statistik \xc3\xb6ver s\xc3\xa5nger\n', 'Antal\tS\xc3\xa5ng', '1\tCarola - Betlehems Stj\xc3\xa4rna', '\n\nStatistik \xc3\xb6ver datak\xc3\xa4llor\n', 'K\xc3\xa4lla\tAntal', 'MANUAL\t1', '\n\nStatistik \xc3\xb6ver \xc3\xb6nskare\n', 'Antal\tId', u'1\tNiclas']
```

When I try to join it with:

```
return '\n'.join(stats_list)
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is it possible to get any clue why this happens just by looking at the list? If I loop over the list and print it to screen, I get this:

```
Statistik över sånger

Antal   Sång 
1   Carola - Betlehems Stjärna


Statistik över datakällor

Källa   Antal 
MANUAL  1


Statistik över önskare

Antal   Id
1   Niclas
```

which is exactly what I was expecting, and no error is shown. (The special characters are swedish).

EDIT:

I'll tried this:

```
   return '\n'.join(i.decode('utf8') for i in stats_list)
```

But it returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./CyberJukebox.py", line 489, in on_stats_to_clipboard
    stats = self.jbox.get_stats()
  File "/home/nine/dev/python/CyberJukebox/jukebox.py", line 235, in get_stats
    return self._stats.get_string()
  File "/home/nine/dev/python/CyberJukebox/jukebox.py", line 59, in get_string
    return '\n'.join(i.decode('utf8') for i in stats_list)
  File "/home/nine/dev/python/CyberJukebox/jukebox.py", line 59, in <genexpr>
    return '\n'.join(i.decode('utf8') for i in stats_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

EDIT 2:

The suggested solution works for me in the interpreter. But when I execute the code it won't work. I can't wrap my head around this. Maybe it's something obvious I'm missing so I'm pasting the whole method here:

```
 def get_string(self):
     stats_list = [u'Statistik över sånger\n', u'Antal\tSång']
     stats = sorted([(v, k) for k, v in self.song_stats.iteritems()], reverse=True)
     for row in stats:
         line = '%s\t%s' % row
         stats_list.append(line)

     stats_list.append(u'\n\nStatistik över datakällor\n')
     stats_list.append(u'Källa\tAntal')
     stats = sorted([(k, v) for k, v in self.exts_stats.iteritems()])
     for row in stats:
         line = '%s\t%s' % row
         stats_list.append(line)

     stats_list.append(u'\n\nStatistik över önskare\n')
     stats_list.append(u'Antal\tId')
     stats = sorted([(v, k) for k, v in self.wisher_stats.iteritems() if k != ''], reverse=True)
     for row in stats:
         line = '%s\t%s' % row
         stats_list.append(line)

     return '\n'.join(i.decode('utf8') for i in stats_list)
```

`song_stats`, `exts_stats` and `wisher_stats` are dictionaries in the class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you are mixing unicode strings with byte strings.

The code in "Edit 2" has several *unicode* strings being added to `stats_list`:

```
stats_list = [u'Statistik över sånger\n', u'Antal\tSång']
```

If you try to *decode* these unicode strings, you will get a `UnicodeEncodeError`. This because Python will first try to use the default encoding (usually "ascii") to *encode* the strings before trying to *decode* them. It only ever makes sense to decode *byte* strings.

So to start with, change the final line in the function to:

```
return '\n'.join(stats_list)
```

Now you need to check whether any of the other strings that get added to `stats_list` are *byte* strings, and ensure they get decoded to *unicode* strings properly first.

So put `print type(line)` after the three lines like this:

```
line = '%s\t%s' % row
```

and then wherever it prints `<type 'str'>`, change the *following* line to:

```
stats_list.append(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

Of course, if it prints `<type 'unicode'>`, there's no need to change the following line.

A even better solution here would be to check how the dictionaries `song_stats`, `exts_stats` and `wisher_stats` are created, and make sure they always contain unicode strings (or byte strings that only contain ascii characters).

Comment: Also consider upgrading to Python 3.x, which has a much cleaner distinction between strings and `bytes`.

Comment: Thanks. I did'nt exactly do as you said. But you got me to understand the problem so now it's working (I think). I ended adding .encode('utf8') on a unicodestring. and deleted all u:s before the manually added strings. I don't know if all my libraries I need for this project supports Python 3 yet... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7):

The strings are encoded in UTF-8. You need to `.decode` them to a `unicode`:

```
>>> 'Statistik \xc3\xb6ver s\xc3\xa5nger\n'.decode('utf-8')
u'Statistik \xf6ver s\xe5nger\n'
>>> print _
Statistik över sånger
```

Use comprehension to perform this to all elements:

```
return '\n'.join(x.decode('utf-8') for x in stats_list)
```

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: It does work with the `stats_list` you've provided in Python 2.7.

Comment: But... I works in the interpreter but not when I'm running the code? WHAT?

Comment: Yeah. Just realised it works in the interpreter... But not in the code... Very strange. I must be doing something wrong..

Comment: I may be stupid... But I can't get it to work... I added some code up there again.

Answer (score 1):

Python is complaining that it can't convert the string `'Statistik \xc3\xb6ver s\xc3\xa5nger\n'` to an ASCII string.  Try prefixing all your UNICODE strings with `u`.

```
stats_list = [u'Statistik \xc3\xb6ver s\xc3\xa5nger\n', u'Antal\tS\xc3\xa5ng', u'1\tCarola - Betlehems Stj\xc3\xa4rna', u'\n\nStatistik \xc3\xb6ver datak\xc3\xa4llor\n', u'K\xc3\xa4lla\tAntal', u'MANUAL\t1', u'\n\nStatistik \xc3\xb6ver \xc3\xb6nskare\n', u'Antal\tId', u'1\tNiclas']
```